# Terrafrom import GCP IAM member from list of users

Tags: terraform-provider-gcp, google-iam

I want to import existing IAM users into terraform. I have created a module in the main.tf that looks like this

```
module "iam" {
  source = "./modules/iam"

  project_id      = var.project_id
  owners          = var.owners
}
```

The variable is defined in the variable file as:

```
 variable "owners" {
      type = list(string)
      default = [
        "user:test1@infarm.com",
        "user:test2@infarm.com",
      ]
    }
```

The module itself contains a resource with a for_each loop as:

```
resource "google_project_iam_member" "owner" {
  role = "roles/owner"
  for_each = toset(concat(
    var.owners,
  ))
  member = each.value
}
```

I have found the import statement from the [terraform documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/google_project_iam#import) and interpreted it as the following. According to the documentation this last part user:foo@example.com only applies to a single user. How can I adjust the import statement to apply to the variable list of users that I want?

```
terraform import module.iam.google_project_iam_member.owner "infarm-data roles/owner user:foo@example.com"
```

Comment: Have you tried an import into `module.iam.google_project_iam_member.owner[0]` and other indices after that?

Comment: I believe this would be a solution if I were using count in the resource creation, but with for_each that wouldn't be possible.

Comment: Ah, I missed that, in that case it should be `module.iam.google_project_iam_member.owner["some_owner"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to above import issue. The solution required two adjustments.

- Reference to the specific item in the for_each loop ["user"] - as mentioned by @luk2302
- quotes around the module statement to be interpreted correctly by the import (as shown below)

```
terraform import  'module.iam.google_project_iam_member.owner["user:foo@example.com"]' "infarm-data roles/owner user:foo@example.com"
```

Hope this is helpful for someone else